# Magento - custom invoice number

Tags: magento, invoice

I need to modify my default invoice number from `100000001` to `2012 - 00001`.

I know where I can found `increment_last_id` in table `eav_entity_store`. But I don't know what I must set that to be taken new format of invoice number.

Please help with some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it manually then take a look @ [How to Change the Invoice Increment ID and Prefix in Magento](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/) (remember to always make a backup)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize order/invoice/creditmemo/shipment number (`increment_id`) by editing the following class:

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric
```

Especially, closely look at the code of the following methods:

`getNextId()`, `getPrefix()`, `getPadLength()`, `format($id)`

Now, you won't find the method definition for methods `getPrefix()`, `getPadLength()` because these are magic getter methods. You can define these methods according to your desire.

For an example:

```
public function getPrefix(){

     $prefix = $this->_getData('prefix');

     /* Do some customization */

    return $prefix;
} 
public function getPadLength()
{ 
     $padLength = $this->_getData('pad_length');

     /* Do some customization */

     return $padLength;
}
```

This way, you don't have to manually change anything in the database structures for this to achieve.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change invoice id is to run following simple sql query:

1. Check if invoice record exist in eav_entity_store table by running following query

   select * from eav_entity_store where entity_type_id in (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code='invoice');
2. If no record exists, create one dummy invoice from magento backend. Then you will have one record in the table, now run following script:

   update eav_entity_store set increment_last_id="YOUR_DESIRED_INVOICE_ID", increment_prefix='X-' where entity_type_id in (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code='invoice')

Try this out and create new invoice:

update eav_entity_store set increment_last_id="0001", increment_prefix='2002' where entity_type_id in (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code='invoice')

http://deepakbhatta.com/magento-set-custom-invoice-id/

This works fine to me.

Thanks